# formatting content of a list item

Tags: html, css, listings

Alright, so I am beginner, and I am trying to format some list items in a certain way. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/dybne8J.jpg) is an example of how I want to list things.

I tried a few ways to do this. My first attempt :

```css
#ingredients {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ingredients">
  <li>1. 8 oz. Gram flour</li>
  <li>1 tsp baking powder</li>
  <li>1 tsp curry powder</li>
  <li>½ tsp salt</li>
  <li>2. 2 eggs (separated)</li>
  <li>2 oz. of melted butter</li>
  <li>3. 1 ½ cup of water</li>
</ul>
```

but I found the formating wasn't quite right. Then I tried this:

```html
<ol id="ingredients">
  <li>8 oz. Gram flour 1 tsp baking powder 1 tsp curry powder ½ tsp salt</li>
  <li>2 eggs (separated) 2 oz. of melted butter</li>
  <li>3. 1 ½ cup of water</li>
</ol>
```

But obvious the texts displays horizontally.

I tried using a grid display, which worked, but I needed to change the size of the column manually and I would like something that adjustes automatically.

I thought about using javaScript to place an array within the content of each list item, but I couldn't really get that to work either...

Any advice on how to get this formated the way I want it.

Comment: It is not related to [tag:javascript].

Comment: "*...I found the formating wasn't quite right.*" What wasn't quite right about it? Are you trying to include the item numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understandings, you're trying to make nested lists. First one is an `ordered` and inside one is an `unordered list`.

I think this is what you're looking for.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>8 oz. Gram flour</li>
      <li>1 tsp baking powder</li>
      <li> 1 tsp curry powder</li>
      <li>½ tsp salt</li>    
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>2 eggs (separated)</li>
      <li> 2 oz. of melted butter</li>
      <li>3. 1 ½ cup of water</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
     <ul>
       <li>Next sub-list item</li>
       <li>Next sub-list item</li>
       <li>Next sub-list item</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel so embarassed for not thinking of this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to this:

```css
ul#ingredients li { display: block; }
```

This will make it so the elements of the list are on seperate lines and not next to each other. I believe that's what you wanted to do right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "list inside a list" format, like this:

```css
#ingredients li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol id="ingredients">
      <li>1. 8 oz. Gram flour</li>
      <li>1 tsp baking powder</li>
      <li>1 tsp curry powder</li>
      <li>½ tsp salt</li>
      <li>2. 2 eggs (separated)</li>
      <li>2 oz. of melted butter</li>
      <li>3. 1 ½ cup of water</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ol>(Step 2)</ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I don't know why you're using `ol` and then explicitly making its ` list-style-type: none;` when you can directly use`ul`

Comment: @Siraj Not sure I follow you -- `ul` would use a disc for each element by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mix of `ol` and `ul` and add control to padding of `ul` to adjust the separating distance between sub items and their parent ordered list item.

HTML:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1.1</li>
      <li>Item 1.2</li>
      <li>Item 1.3</li>
      <li>Item 1.4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>
      <li>Item 2.2</li>
      <li>Item 2.3</li>
      <li>Item 2.4</li>
      <li>Item 2.5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol li ul{
      padding-left: 7px; /* The distance between list number and item */
    }
    ol li ul li{
      list-style: none;      
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/lahezacizi/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the nested listing structure to get your result like below

```css
#ingredients {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#ingredients>li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#ingredients>li>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ol id="ingredients">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>1. 8 oz. Gram flour</li>
      <li>1 tsp baking powder</li>
      <li>1 tsp curry powder</li>
      <li>½ tsp salt</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>2. 2 eggs (separated)</li>
      <li>2 oz. of melted butter</li>
      <li>3. 1 ½ cup of water</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I don't know why you're using `ul` and then explicitly defining `list-style-type: decimal;` when you can directly use `ol`.